MAUI, how to managed culture in converter?
I am using LocalizationResourceManager
public class LocalizationResourceManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private LocalizationResourceManager()
    {
        Strings.Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }

    public static LocalizationResourceManager Instance { get; } = new();

    public object this[string resourceKey]
        => Strings.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey, Strings.Culture) ??
        Array.Empty<byte>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public string GetString(string resourceKey, CultureInfo? culture)
    {
        return Strings.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceKey, culture)!;
    }

    public void SetCulture(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Strings.Culture = culture;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
    }
}

I use it with TranslateExtension:
[ContentProperty(nameof(Name))]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new Binding
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = $"[{Name}]",
            Source = LocalizationResourceManager.Instance
        };
    }

    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}

like:
<Label Text="{local:Translate MESSAGE}"/>

And it works fine, when I change culture in my service via:
public void SetLanguage(LanguageType language)
{
    switch (language)
    {
        case LanguageType.ENG:
            LocalizationResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(new CultureInfo("en"));
            break;
        case LanguageType.DE:
            LocalizationResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(new CultureInfo("de"));
            break;
        default:
            LocalizationResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(new CultureInfo("en"));
            break;
    }
}

Everything works fine and text has changed dynamically.
But how can I use it with IValueConverter:
public class IsConnectedToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object? value, Type? targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo? culture)
    {
        if (value is bool isConnected)
        {
            return isConnected switch
            {
                true => "Con.",
                false => "Discon.",
            };
        }
        return "Discon.";
    }

    public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

Most of my texts are changing dynamically according to variable and converter handle this. But how can I managed dynamically changing language with converter?

Don't know about maui, but in wpf you'll either need to refresh the binding, which forces convertion or to use multibinding converter to monitor for language changes as well.

Check if this wpf topic is helpful.

I am thinking replace converter by DataTriggers could be easier.

Integrating the Translate method into the Converter could be a workaround.
